# How to set cursor in textfield in fleet

Tags: flet

I'm trying to usre Flet, but is not seems has avery simple function to set cursor in a TextField, it's very useless to put all the configurations to the cursor, but the most simple thing such as set in a determinate position a TextField
i tried with focus, but always goes to the start of the textfield

```
TextField(label="", value="|", max_lines= 6, 
            min_lines=6, expand=True, bgcolor='#8FBF62', color = ft.colors.BLACK, 
            disabled=False, text_size= 25, cursor_width=2, cursor_color=ft.colors.BLACK,
            keyboard_type=ft.KeyboardType.NONE, autofocus=True, on_change=self.set_cur)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the text within the `TextField` to include spaces or other characters before the desired cursor position. Here's an example of how you can set the cursor position to the 5th character in a `TextField`.

```
import flet as ft

class MyTextFieldApp(ft.App):
    def build(self):
        text = "     |"  # Add spaces before the cursor position
        text_field = ft.TextField(
            label="",
            value=text,
            max_lines=6,
            min_lines=6,
            expand=True,
            bgcolor='#8FBF62',
            color=ft.colors.BLACK,
            disabled=False,
            text_size=25,
            cursor_width=2,
            cursor_color=ft.colors.BLACK,
            keyboard_type=ft.KeyboardType.NONE,
            autofocus=True,
            on_change=self.set_cursor_position,
        )
        return text_field

    def set_cursor_position(self, text):
        # Remove spaces and other characters before processing
        text = text.replace(" ", "")
        
        # Now you can work with the cleaned text
        cursor_position = 5  # Set the desired cursor position
        if cursor_position < len(text):
            text = text[:cursor_position] + "|" + text[cursor_position:]
        
        # Add spaces back to maintain the formatting
        text = " " * (cursor_position + 1) + text[cursor_position + 1:]
        
        return text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyTextFieldApp().run()
```

Comment: Not exactly what a was thinking,, but that solution worked for me thx